# How do I get the most recent version of SQL Server on my computer?

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I created a database in Visual Studio 2015 community. I wanted to open it in SQl Server Management Studio. So I downloaded Management Studio 2014 and I get the following error: "cannot be opened because it is version 782. This version supports 706 and earlier."

If I look in the root of the object explorer it says the SQL Server is v 11.0.2100 which, when I run the version command appears to be v12. When I look at the About on the Management Studio, it says its version 2014...and all of the SQL components in the app list say 2014.

I've tried multiple downloads trying to get the most recent version. If I grab 2014 and try to upgrade it, it won't let me...it says I've already got the components. Tried rebooting too. How do I get the most recent version of SQL Server on my computer?!

Comment: This article demonstrates a person how a person would connect to SQL Server 2014 through an older version of VS. That is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: That *article* explains precisely why you're getting the error message you're seeing. Read it more carefully.

Comment: This is not a SQL related issue. You need to search windows registry and find the biggest version.